# Promises.all does not hit catch() block when one promise fails?

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js

I'm trying to run a function when two compilation steps are complete, but the success callback keeps getting called even one fails. Here's the code:

```
function compile(tplStr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    // compile template here
    var tpl = new function(){};
    resolve(tpl);
  });
}

function parse(json) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    try {
      var obj = JSON.parse(json);
      resolve(obj);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('JSON parse failed');
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

var i = 0;

function bothReady() {
  $('#c').text(++i);
}

function oneFailed(err) {
  console.log('oneFailed hit');
  $('#c').text(err.message);
}

var compileProm = compile($('#a').val());
var parseProm = parse($('#b').val());

Promise.all([compileProm,parseProm]).then(bothReady).catch(oneFailed);


$('#a').on('input', function() {
  Promise.all([compile($('#a').val()),parseProm]).then(bothReady).catch(oneFailed);
});


$('#b').on('input', function() {
  Promise.all(compileProm,parse($('#b').val())).then(bothReady).catch(oneFailed);
});
```

[code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iowfn?editors=101)

When I create a syntax error in the JSON portion it logs "JSON parse failed" but does *not* log "oneFailed hit" like I'd expect. Why not? Shouldn't the `.catch` block be ran if any of the promises are rejected?

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kDtCa) after I added jQuery and RSVP to the code pen.

Comment: However, your code sometimes does log `oneFailed hit` but *not* `JSON.parse failed` because you didn't update the `compileProm` and `parseProm` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work correctly when something is typed inside of `#b` because instead of passing an iterable to `Promise.All` 2 parameters are passed instead.

The result is that while both promises run, only the result of the first one is taken into account by the continuation of `all`.

The code read

```
Promise.all(compileProm,parse($('#b').val())).then(bothReady).catch(oneFailed);
```

Instead of

```
Promise.all([compileProm,parse($('#b').val())]).then(bothReady).catch(oneFailed);
```

*PS*: The 2 other calls are correct it explain why the problem seem to happen only when editing the JSON.